# Regarding angle of contact and capillary tube of insufficient length

Tags: fluid-statics, surface-tension, capillary-action

It is written in my book that when a capillary tube is of insufficient length, the liquid does not overflow and the shape of the liquid meniscus changes, but the angle of contact remains the same. I did not understand that how it is possible because,
$$r=R\cos\theta,$$
where

- $R$ is the radius of curvature of liquid meniscus
- $r$ is the radius of capillary tube.

As the shape is changing, hence $R$ is changing; but $r$ is a constant so $\cos\theta$ must change.

**So why does angle of contact not change when the radius of curvature is changing?**

Answer (score 0):

When a capillary tube is of insufficient length, once the liquid rises up and reaches the top of the tube it adjusts its radius of curvature instead of overflowing.Due to this **the contact angle will change**.
Consider the image:[image]

r denotes radius of tube.

R denotes the radius of curvature of the liquid meniscus.

*θ* denotes the normal contact angle that the liquid has.

*θ'* denotes the contact angle of the liquid when the tube has insufficient length.

Let *h* is the sufficient height that the capillary tube must have so that the contact angle remains same

***h=$\frac{2Tcos θ}{\rho gr}$***

Let *h'* is the height of the tube which is of insufficient length.

***h'=$\frac{2Tcos θ'}{\rho gr}$***

Hence *h* and *h'* can be related by the following relation.

***$\frac{h}{h'}$=$\frac{cos\theta}{cos\theta'}$***

In conclusion, yes the contact angle will change when the tube is of insufficient length and clearly, it increases.
.